# Angular 12 Use pipe from component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

Hello I have problems to use from a component in Angular 12 (from the view if it works).

It is a pipe that I installed, although I have already tried with several and the same thing happens.

Specifically, it is this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@josee9988/filter-pipe-ngx

I do this:

```
app.module.ts

..

import { FilterModule } from '@josee9988/filter-pipe-ngx';
..

imports: [FilterModule],
..

providers: [FilterModule],
..
```

Y en comp1.component.ts

```
import { FilterModule } from '@josee9988/filter-pipe-ngx';

..

constructor(private FilterModule_: FilterModule) { }

..

funcion1 () {
   this.v1 = this.FilterModule_.transform(this.v2, "gfg", v3);
}

..
```

And he tells me that "error TS2339: Property 'transform' does not exist on type 'FilterModule'"

And it won't even let me use ng serve.

Thank.

Best regards.

Comment: Typo? `private FilterModule_: FilterModulee` » `private FilterModule_: FilterModule` and you should use `this.FilterModule_` and not `this.FilterModule`

Comment: It was already like that, I copied it wrong.

Comment: What module is `comp1.component` declared in? That's the module where you need to import `FilterModule`. Then you can inject the `FilterPipe` in your `comp1.component`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You trying to inject a module, but you need a pipe.

```
constructor(private filterPipe: FilterPipe) { }
...
this.filterPipe.transform(...)
```

If you will catch NullInjector just provide FilterPipe in the module.

```
providers: [FilterPipe]
```

Comment: (2) or import the `FilterModule`

Comment: I remember some cases when it didn't work for using pipes inside the component, but should. but my mind totally agrees with you  :)